# How to terminate a Java Application from a C# service

Tags: c#, java, windows-services, batch-file, restart

I am trying to develop a log file watchdog C# service to restart a Java application.

This Java application runs a special communication program and writes collected data to a log file. It is currently being started with a batch file script.

I want my C# service to monitor whether or not the log file is updated with new data. If it isn't getting new data, I want to restart the Java application.

I have found material online about calling batch scripts in C# applications and checking when files are modified, but I was wondering if their is a way to terminate the currently running Java Program using a C# application? The Java programs name is javaw.exe, but their are other Java programs running on this machine so it isn't unique. Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What you probably want is PowerShell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jps -v is a Java command which details out the processes which are being used by java. If you make this call via c# and pass the information into a string, you can sort through this and determine precisely which process you'd like to kill.

You can take in the output like so:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("jps", "-v");
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
        string[] output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Split("\n".ToCharArray());
```

After this, you can easily parse out the Process ID and Name of the Java process you're running.

Comment: please note that this is assuming that you have the Java SDK installed on the machine. If the app is going to be run on a machine where only the JRE is installed and not the SDK, the call for that process will not work as the files will be missing. You may want to include the necessary SDK files with your application if you are planning on deployment. But please make sure to read the EULA for Java before doing so to make sure you are doing so within their guidelines

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice to shutdown programs gracefully, i.e. send some kind of signal that politely asks program to terminate. If you are on pure java environment I'd recommend you to use JMX for this, but since your watchdog is in C# you can send signal using plain TCP sockets. This way is good if you can modify the java program to be able to receive such signal.

To *kill* any process you can use either `killtask` command or C# API that kills process identified by PID. It is not a trivial task to find PID of running java process on windows. But you can use command `jps` that prints all java processes with their main class name and arguments.

You can pass special identifier to your java program using `-D` option:
`java -Dmyid=1234 MyClass arg1 arg2`

Store 1234 (myid) in C# program. Then when you want to check whether the java program is still running execute `jps`, parse its output, get the process with parameter `-Dmyid=1234`, get its PID returned by `jps` and kill the process.

Comment: So I can use the -DmyId option when I run my program to give it a unique Id? Would I have to worry about any other existing ids if the id I choose already exists? I was thinking about trying to rename javaw.exe using a solution like launch4j, but if setting the process Id is easier, I would prefer it because my Java program has enough dependencies to get it working [ini-4j and a special third party communication protocol].